# Is it possible to use 'sharey=row' with 'subplot_mosaic'

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a possibility to use [sharey='row'](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) with `plt.subplot_mosaic()`? I know I could [share the axis for a pair of subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.sharey.html), but this requires calling the function for all subplots individually, on the other hand `sharey='row'` is single call.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [A * np.sinc(np.linspace(0, 10, 100)) for A in (1,2)]

nrows = 1
ncols = 2
fig_kw = dict(figsize=(ncols*3, nrows*1.8), layout='constrained')
mosaic = [['t1', 't2']]

fig, axs = plt.subplot_mosaic(mosaic=mosaic, **fig_kw)
axs['t1'].plot(x[0])
axs['t2'].plot(x[1])
```

[image]

Using `fig_kw = dict(figsize=(ncols*3, nrows*1.8), sharey= 'row', layout='constrained')` results in:

> `'sharey' must be an instance of bool, not a str`

I tried using `fig_kw`, but I got the same error.

Comment: [**sharex, sharey bool, default: False
If True, the x-axis (sharex) or y-axis (sharey) will be shared among all subplots. In that case, tick label visibility and axis units behave as for subplots. If False, each subplot's x- or y-axis will be independent.**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot_mosaic.html)

Comment: `fig, axs = plt.subplot_mosaic(mosaic=mosaic, sharey=True, **fig_kw)` works without issue. As does `dict(figsize=(ncols*3, nrows*1.8), layout='constrained', sharey=True)`. The error already said it must be a bool. **I'm voting to close this as caused by a typo / not reproducible.**

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney: I don't understand the typo problem. I know how to use sharey with a bool. I'm asking whether it is possible to share y on a whole row, when using `plt.subplot_mosaic()`, like it is possible with `plt.subplots()`. Maybe the answer is no, but there is no typo in my question.

Comment: The close option is **Not reproducible or was caused by a typo**. I understand your question, but the documentation for `.subplot_mosaic` already tells you the form acceptable for `sharey`. So passing `'row'`, intentionally, or otherwise, seems like a typo **as it relates to the documentation**.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney: Perhaps you're right, but there are multiple ways to provide parameters, and I wonder if it can be done using indirect settings via `fig_kw`, as suggested by "*All additional keyword arguments are passed to the pyplot.figure call". `figure` itself [has optional kw](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html): *Additional keyword arguments are passed to the Figure constructor*, it's not as easy has you explained.